# Replace MergeField of DOCX in PHP

Tags: php, ms-word, docx, mergefield

I have a Word template (DOCX) with mergefields and many condition with this mergefields.

For example :

[image]

I want to complete the mergefields in PHP.

I know that a data source can be given to WORD to do that but i don't know how to do this in PHP.

Have you a solution please ?

Comment: Can you use C#? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400152/how-can-i-put-a-content-in-a-mergefield-in-docx

Comment: I can execute C# in PHP ?